# PLSQL NOT IN ('val1','val2') not working in procedure

Tags: sql, database, plsql

I have a string of primary keys as key = '1234','5678','9876' received as parameter of a procedure.

```
  PROCEDURE DeleteRecord(vKey varchar2) AS
   BEGIN    
     delete FROM tableName WHERE key NOT IN (vKey);  
    EXCEPTION
      WHEN OTHERS THEN
    RAISE;
  END DeleteRecord;
```

My aim here is to delete everything that is in the table other than the comma separated recieved keys.
If i just run the query with hard coded values, it seems to be running fine. but when i execute it in the procedure and call the procedure it doesn't work. What is wrong here.
Are there any other alternatives to NOT IN when i receive comma separated keys.

Comment: Check out https://asktom.oracle.com/pls/apex/f?p=100:11:0::::p11_question_id:210612357425

Comment: btw you can massively improve the exception handling by removing `when others then raise;`

Comment: Also, the way `PROCEDURE`, `BEGIN` and `EXCEPTION` don't quite line up (and `RAISE` is left of its parent `WHEN`) is seriously triggering my OCD :)